# What 'rated voltage' means in VDE certificates?

Tags: safety, maximum-ratings, certification

In a VDE certificate for a component (plugin green terminal blocks), a column gives the "Rated voltage(s) / V" with a value of "400" without specification wether it's VAC or VDC.

Does this mean that the component is safe to use for both DC and AC at this voltage ?

A 400VAC voltage will be applied on the component (three phases, one neutral, one earth wire / Europe). As the voltage on the  electrical network can fluctuate, is this "rated voltage" given with these variations taken in consideration ?

[image: VDE certificate (extract)]

Comment: Could you please share a link to this VDE certificate?

Comment: https://www2.vde.com/EN/INSTITUTE/ONLINESERVICE/VDE-APPROVED-PRODUCTS/Pages/ProductDetails.aspx?cid=fef22b492a3e44219a6d968acc21e550
It's in Appendix 200A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike switch contacts that can break inductive current, without looking up the relevant std. specs. I say **both AC & DC**.

It's my opinion that the  basic insulation here applies to both AC_rms and DC.  For moving contacts the DC rating can be <1/3 Vac rating which does not apply here.

These tests include lightning impulse AC voltage.  There would be some industrial contamination level provided in the spec.

There is no reason to derate a Terminal block for DC vs AC so the same level applies.  That would be true for 70kVdc as it is for 400Vdc. Beyond this the pollution level is a critical factor design factors for creepage, which does not apply here, just FYI.

**If you are doubtful on the pollution or dust levels, add a dust shield.**

Comment: Yes. It's rated for pollution degree 2 and material group I. Now I'm still unsure if the connector is adapted because the voltages varies between 360VAC and 440VAC. So maybe out of specs ?

Comment: pollution degree 2 includes most Office and laboratory areas

Comment: The board is put in IP65 junction box in building technical rooms. So a pretty clean environment that should correspond to pollution degree 2 in my opinion. But what if the electrical grid voltage varies and goes up to 440VAC (which is considered ok) ? That's my last interrogation.

Comment: 10% tolerance is normal

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Help appreciated.